Bind9 signed zone SOA serial update does not reflect usigned serial
I am using BIND 9.18.28-0ubuntu0.24.04.1-Ubuntu to serve DNSSEC signed zones but when I update a zone the SOA serial for the signed zone does not relate to the unsigned SOA.
After the last update my zonefile for the usigned zone has the SOA serial 2024081200 but the signed version of the zone has serial 2024040710.
If I make a change to the zonefile and change the SOA serial to 2024081301 and reload Bind the signed serial changes to 2024040711.
It seems no matter what changes I do the serial for the signed zone is only incremeted by one. I want it to use the serial of the unsigned zone file as the new base for the signed serial (incrementing it by one when keys are rotated).
The zone is configured like this
zone "example.com" IN {
    type primary;
    file "/var/cache/bind/zones/example.com";
    dnssec-policy default;
    inline-signing yes;
};

And my dnssec-policy looks like this
dnssec-policy standard {
    dnskey-ttl 600;
    keys {
            ksk lifetime P365D algorithm ecdsap256sha256;
            zsk lifetime P60D algorithm ecdsap256sha256;
    };
    max-zone-ttl P1D;
    parent-ds-ttl PT1H;
    parent-propagation-delay PT1H;
    publish-safety PT1H;
    retire-safety PT1H;
    signatures-refresh P5D;
    signatures-validity P14D;
    signatures-validity-dnskey P14D;
    zone-propagation-delay PT5M;
};

What am I missing?

This seems to be deliberate, as far as I can see in lib/dns/zone.c, which was made to always ignore the SOA of the insecure zone way back in BIND 9.7.x, with a changelog entry that only says:
3289.   [bug]           'rndc retransfer' failed for inline zones. [RT #28036]

(The referenced ISC RT item doesn't seem to be publicly viewable, unfortunately.)
In other words, it always overwrites the serial in SOA with oldserial+1, and there seems to be no option to disable this behavior.


Personally, I do not find the date-based serial numbers useful at all. Smaller integers are easier to update, and easier to compare visually – it took more than just a glance to interpret the ones in your question. The question of "when was the zone updated last" can be answered by Git/Hg/CVS; failure to load a zone is already detected during rndc reload (and usually can be caught preemptively by running named-checkzone as a Git hook); stuck replication is easy to see from dig +nssearch.
Note that DNSSEC signatures have a relatively short expiry time, so the SOA serial number isn't only bumped during key rotation – it is also bumped every time a signature expires and has to be re-signed, which seems to be every ~5 days in your configuration.
(Although your zone definition doesn't use the "standard" policy that you've defined – it uses the "default" policy...)
(On the topic of expiry, you definitely do not need 60-day rotation for an EC P-256 ZSK – that was something that used to be done in the days of 768-bit RSA zone keys, a compromise with using weak keys to obtain smaller signatures, which does not apply to EC.)

Good catch with standard vs default.
I have somehow managed to get a higher serial in the slave servrers. No idea how, but zones could have been faulty as I was still trying things out so I'd really want to be able to update the signed serial.
